# RactiveJS dynamic variable name

Tags: ractivejs

I'm curious if I can somehow use dynamic variable names in templates. For example, I'm having a loop, though a type of units in my game:

```
{{# config.units:unit }}
    <input type="text" id="unit_{{unit}}" class="toTrain selectable" value="" placeholder="0" />
{{/ config }}
```

Where the value of the input should return the value of {{units_1}} for example, which represents the amount of units (type 1).

I could easily do some external object and store the amount of units for each of them but, I was wondering if I can keep the data binded because somewhere in the template there will be a total needed resources which is calculated whith these values.

The only "solution" which came into my head was to get rid of the loop and manually write the units in the template. But, when units change, I also need to change the template, and.. the real template structure for one unit is a bit bigger than this snippet.

Example:

```
<input value="{{units_1}}" />
<input value="{{units_2}}" />
```

And I was looking for something like:

```
<input value="{{'units_'+unit}}" />
```

Which is obviously not working and not even supposed to work this way. But, thats why I'm here right ? To raise questions.

Regards !

Comment: Can you provide sample data that shows what you want to switch between and what you're calculating totals on? I don't understand how you got to needing to do this.

Comment: @martypdx a simple example is this, you have an object with key/values like `unit_1 => 10`, `unit_2 => 15`. In the template I have these unit types shown in a list and I would like to train more units. So I have inputs structured like value="{{units_amount.unit_1}}". So far so good, but, I render the list in a loop like this `{{# config.units:unit}}` which goes through all the units and renders the input html so I can train some more. Here's the problem, the ":unit" index is variable so I can't use value="{{units_amount.unit_1}}" because `unit_1` should be `unit_{{unit}}` ($unit_$id in PHP)

Comment: In PHP I can simply do this by using `$a = 'hello'`, `$$a = 'world'`. Hope you get the point, it's called Variable Variables in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use write `getUnit` function:

```
{{# config.units:unit }}
    <input type="text" id="{{ getUnit(unit) }}" class="toTrain selectable" value="" placeholder="0" />
{{/ config }}
```

Component:

```
Ractive.extend({
  init:function(){
        self.set("getUnit", function (id) {
            return self.get("config.units.unit_"+id);
        });
  }
})
```