# RactiveJS iterator (for) structure

Tags: ractivejs

I'm wondering if , for example I have `number_of_fields => 2` and I'd like to show up two input texts like this:

```
{{ # number_of_fields }}
   <input type="text" />
{{ / fields }}
```

Doing this, obviously results in one input since the parameter I'm passing (`number_of_fields`) is actually one simple element. What I'm trying to accomplish is an "add new field" feature in a CV generator, and I'd like doing it "automatically" with ractive instead of just adding a new `element` with JS manually on-click.

Comment: I'm really not sure, but have you tried something like this: {{#[1,#fields]:i}}

Answer (score 2):

I found a way which I consider to be really useful. Even if there would be any "easy" or natural way to do a `for` in `RactiveJS` we may still find ourselves in need of `binding` or `controlling` the data so if we would have this :

{{ # fields_number:num }}
    
{{ / fields }}

That's quite bad of a method for getting those values binded, and I am sure we all agree. Now, what I've asked a while ago here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460380/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460380/ractivejs-dynamic-variable-name) is quite the same situation.

**But then it struck me !**

I thought about having an `array` of `x null values` where `x` would be the `number of inputs` in my case.

```
...
data : {
    groups : [ 'group1', 'group2', ...],
    fields : { 
        group1 : [ null, null ],
        group2 : [ null, null, null ],
        ...
}
...
```

Then it'll be way easier to bind the data, directly into these values like this:

```
{{ # groups:number }}
    <div id="{{ . }}">
        {{ # fields[ groups[ number ] ]:index }}
            <input type="text" value="{{ fields[ groups[ number ] ][ index ] }}" />
        {{ / fields }}
    </div>
{{ / groups }}
```

Now, you have a `ractive.get( 'fields' )` full binded data :). Hope this helps !